# Issue while Setup Habitat 1.8.1 on Sitecore 9.2 "Error: spawn C:\Windows\microsoft.net\Framework64\v(not used)\msbuild.exe ENOENT"

Tags: habitat

I face an issue while setup Habitat 1.8.1 on Sitecore 9.2

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 **installed in 'D' drive, not in 'C' drive**, node 10.18.0, gulp CLI version: 2.3.0, gulp Local version: 3.9.1.

I noticed that code try to use MSBuild from the "C" drive maybe this is an old installation,
but new visual studio 2019 and MSBuild installed in "D" drive.

[image: build error]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to add ***VS installation path*** to your system environment variables under the name of ***vsInstallDir***( No need to uninstall VS and reinstall on Drive C)

[image: Configuring Environment Variables]

Answer (score 1):

Habitat Gulp build script is using [gulp-msbuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msbuild) plugin to create the msbuild cmd. Behind the scene, if you look within gulp-msbuild in your node-modules or in the official repos [here](https://github.com/fluffynuts/gulp-msbuild/tree/master/lib), you can find the [msbuild-finder](https://github.com/fluffynuts/gulp-msbuild/blob/master/lib/msbuild-finder.js) code where you will also find hardcoded path to where it looks for msbuild (C:/)

```
// Line 247,      
  let pathRoot = process.env["ProgramFiles"] || "C:/Program Files";
  if (hostIs64Bit) {
      pathRoot = process.env["ProgramFiles(x86)"] || "C:/Program Files (x86)";
  }
  let msbuildRoot = pathRoot;
  let toolsVersion = parseFloat(options.toolsVersion);
// ...
```

So you could console.log() within that file and have a better understanding of what is happening.

Also note that this plugin was blacklisted in the official gulp plugin directory. Can use the [msbuild plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msbuild) instead which would lead you to the exact same issue because it is also looking at C:/ by default. You can define what msbuild version to use with the **version** switch, but would only lead to the local path to msbuild within the C: drive.

Side note : I think it is more flexible to create an msbuild cmd and easier since you can add any of the offical msbuild switch ([doc here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019)) as an override param. Could end up with something similar to

```
var overrideParams = [];
overrideParams.push(`/t:${targets}`,
    `/v:${config.solution.buildVerbosity}`,
    '/nologo',
    `/m:${config.solution.buildMaxCpuCount}`,
    '/nr:False',
    `/p:Configuration=${config.solution.buildConfiguration}`,
    `/p:Platform=${config.solution.buildPlatform}`,
    '/p:DeployOnBuild=true',
    '/p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish',
    '/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem',
    '/p:DeleteExistingFiles=false',
    `/p:publishUrl=${dest}`,
    '/p:_FindDependencies=true');

msbuild.sourcePath = filePath;
msbuild.config('overrideParams', overrideParams);
msbuild.version = `${config.solution.buildToolsVersion}`;
msbuild.build();
```

So long story short, Gulp's msbuild plugins are not taking into consideration VStudio being installed anywhere but on C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries i had to uninstall visual studio from "D" and remove MSBuild from 'Registry Editor' in this location "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild" and install visual studio again in "C" Drive , which leaded to a new KEY add in the Registry with the correct path of MSBuild